# how to know if user is seeing home page or not?

Tags: drupal-6

today i was doing some java script coding,
in that i need some images only appear on my home page.
so how can know that if user is seeing the home page or not?
or i do this with url check up?
is their in built function check in drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a page.tpl.php or similar you can use $is_front.

> $is_front: TRUE if the current page is
>   the front page. Used to toggle the
>   mission statement.

From: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php